# hide and show frame in tcl tk gui

Tags: user-interface, tcl, tk-toolkit

I want to make a frame that can be hidden and shown alternatively. The problem is Tk does not provide any hide/unpack command. I use vtcl and there is an option "Window hode" which only hides the window at top level. Now I want to hide a frame and later show the same frame again. It can be thought of as unpacking one frame and showing the other. My code can be like this:

```
proc show1hide2 { } {
    global i top
    if {$i == 1} {
        unpack $top.frame1
        pack $top.frame2
        set i 0
    } else {
        unpack $top.frame2
        pack $top.frame1
        set i 1
    }
}
```

In this procedure, `$top.frame1` and `$top.frame2` were previously filled and value of `$i` is toggled hence `$top.frame1` and `$top.frame2` are shown alternatively when this proc is called. All, I want to know is that does there exists and command like `unpack` which can help me do this? By the way, `unpack` here is just an idea.

Comment: There seems to be another solution using "stacked frames" and the `raise` command (I did not try it yet). The advantage could be that the window will not shrink or grow (resize) if the two frames have a different size and a layout manager is used (e. g. `grid´): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19404439/python-tkinter-how-to-hide-the-ui

Answer (score 9):

I think that the **pack forget** command might be what you are looking for:

```
proc toggle {} {
    global state
    if {$state == 1} {
        pack forget .r
        pack .g   -side bottom -fill x
        set state 0
    } else {
        pack forget .g
        pack .r   -side bottom -fill x

        set state 1
    }
}

set state 1

# Make the widgets
label .r -text "Red Widget"    -bg red
label .g -text "Green Widget" -bg green
button .tog -text "Toggle" -command toggle
# Lay them out
pack .tog
pack .r   -side bottom -fill x
```

Comment: +1: You can use `pack info` to get the information to save about the packed window between calls so that the restore works properly. Alternatives are to use `grid` which has `grid remove` as well as `grid forget`, and I think you can configure the `ttk::notebook` widget to not have tabs with a suitable style (which has some advantages with widget layout). Alas, style hacking remains Deep Voodoo to a far greater extent than it should. :-(

Comment: Great code! I just wanted to know whether the windows shrinks and grows between the two `pack` commands (or adjusts the size only after the second pack as needed). Result: No shrink and grow-again, just one window size adjustment after the command handler "toggle" has finished. I have tested this by inserting `after 1000` between the two pack commands (to wait one second). My interpretation: Tcl/Tk is single threaded and must wait until the end of the function execution.